# Soldering alternatives for a relay

Tags: relay, soldering, alternatives

I have to confess that I'm not a handy person thus soldering is too difficult for me. I was researching on the internet about soldering alternatives but all of them are done for soldering 2 cables.
I need an alternative for soldering a cable with a relay (those with 3mm or 4mm pins).

Comment: Find if there is a socket available for the relay you have.

Comment: Is this a question about connecting to a given relay (which you forgot to specify), or do you need advice about which relay to buy so that you don't have to solder?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I have a few of those small blue relays (9v and 5v relays), like the one in the picture of MichaelKeijzers, and I need to solder on wires for using them on breadboards. The Solutions proposed by Neil_UK and MichaelKeijzers are perfect, I didn't know I could purchase this kind of relays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many relays come with flat tab contacts known by brand name as 'faston' or 'lucar', or more generically as spade or [blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_connector#Blade_connector) terminals. These mate with terminals that can be crimped onto wires.

Some relays are available that plug in to bases equipped with screw terminals.

Comment: Do you mean like the picture below?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use dupont cables, like in the picture below.

[image]
<sup>Source: [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506234853/https://des.gbtcdn.com/uploads/2015/201507/heditor/201507271254288929.jpg)</sup>
<sup>Original source: [des.gbtcdn.com](https://des.gbtcdn.com/uploads/2015/201507/heditor/201507271254288929.jpg)</sup>

This only works if the relay or dupont cables do not move (much), since it's not as tight as soldering.